# Насколько оптимальна работа с System.Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, производительность

Волнует вопрос оптимальности работы с LINQ. Один знакомый уверял меня, что когда я вызываю `.ElementAt(N)`, то за сценой происходит нечто подобное:

```
public static T ElementAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Data, int Index)
{
    if (Index < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T x in Data)
        if (i++ == Index) return x;
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Как мы понимаем, эту куда медленнее, чем просто получить элемент по индексу в том же массиве, листе и прочем. Если это действительно так, и

```
a[999]; // int[] a = new int[1000];
```

отработает в ~1000 раз быстрее, чем

```
a.ElementAt(999);
```

то возможно ли создать метод-расширение для всех классов, у которых гарантировано есть индексатор?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Это не совсем так](//referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761). Почти все методы LINQ сначала делают проверку на список. Но если ты и так знаешь, что там список, то используй скобки, а не LINQ. Они же даже короче.

```
public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) return list[index];
    if (index < 0) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (true) {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
            if (index == 0) return e.Current;
            index--;
        }
    }
}
```